# How to create a temporary table using the MEMORY engine like another table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need a temporary table with the same layout as existing one. This throws a syntax error at the `engine` line:

```sql
create table t
like r
engine = MEMORY
```

Or is this not possible?

Comment: there is no option to create..like..engine https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html have you tried ALTER after create(ing) - works for me BTW you aren't creating a temporary table using the published code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create temptable like existing table then alter its engine. Remember that some column datatypes (TEXT/BLOB/JSON) are not supported by MEMORY engine.

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, val VARCHAR(255));
```

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test2 LIKE test1;
```

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE test2;
```

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| test2 | CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test2` ( `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `val` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

```
ALTER TABLE test2 Engine = MEMORY;
```

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE test2;
```

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| test2 | CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test2` ( `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `val` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`) ) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NXmMzldW)

Comment: Thanks that workes with the restriction you mentionend. I actually attempt to use this to stage data from a CSV file and stored the columns in TEXT as I only need the data and never any fancy stuff like keys or indexes. I do see in the docs that selecting from the memory backed table will move it to an aria engine which would defeat my purpose anyway. Or won't it with a unconstraint and unjoined SELECT?

Comment: @theking2 *I actually attempt to use this to stage data from a CSV file and stored the columns in TEXT* Does the data is so long? what is approximate CSV file size and what is maximal data per line length approximately? maybe something like VARCHAR(8000) will be enough?

Comment: With varchar(255) I ran in a per record size limitation. So I decided to keep it in ARIA. Caching in ARIA might actually do everyting in memory anyway. The extract and transfer is done in an transaction and I don't see disk activity during the import. I probably overthought the performance hit.